# How to insert a TextFromfield in row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a two Rows each one contains 8 TextFormField . I tried the following code to create a format

```
....
 Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
 Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      subtitle: TextFormField(
                        controller: _Controller18,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                
            ......   //until 8 TextFormField
```

but I get the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSOD.png) ,i can't input any value at TextFormField (because he has a small size )

clarification :

i Want to achieve a format like shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOTq.png) by using two rows and eight TextFormFields in each row.

what should i do ?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more. So, we can understand your question and help you out to solve it.

Comment: Can you include an image that are trying to archive ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You are free to customize the textfields. But consider the width of each phone screen. if its a website, conisder the responsiveness of the website.

```
Widget x(double width) {
    return SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: Row(children: [
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              )),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          SizedBox(
              width: width / 10,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(filled: true),
              ))
        ]));
  }
}
```

Then access like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            // choose scroll axis
            child: Column(children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 50),
              x(width),
              x(width),
              x(width),
              x(width),
              x(width),
            ])));
  }
```